# How can I return the memory allocation for an array in php?

Tags: php, memory-management

I'd like to know how many bytes an array is allocated in memory.

```
$array = range(0,1000000000);
echo count($array);            // returns number of rows in array (1B);
echo sizeof($array);           // alias of count();
```

How can I make something like this work?

```
echo memory_allocated_to_array($array);
```

Here's a guess based on `memory_get_usage()`:

```
$start_bytes = memory_get_usage();
$array = range(0,1000000000);
$end_bytes = memory_get_usage();
$array_bytes = ($end_bytes - $start_bytes);
echo $array_bytes;
```

But I suspect this is highly inaccurate when multiple processes are running (each with its own memory requirements).

Comment: As far as I'm aware that's the most accurate method, other threads asking the same thing have been answered with the method you're currently using.

Comment: it's not inaccurate. mem_get_usage doesn't report on OTHER php instances. only the particular process/script that the function's called in.

Comment: Is there a race against the GC with a check like this?

Comment: @MarcB, so is my guess based on `memory_get_usage()` the best way to estimate memory allocation for an array in PHP?

Comment: @Ryan No, because you won't be able to repeat the check if you attempt to overwrite the variable, it will only work for newly initialized variables.

Comment: Right @Flosculus. But I suspect one could unset prior to the first `memory_get_usage()`.

Comment: @Ryan please check it out my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the current best answer of which I'm aware (as mentioned in the question above), but I will readily upvote and accept better answers.

```
$start_bytes = memory_get_usage();
$array = range(0,1000000000);
$end_bytes = memory_get_usage();
$array_bytes = ($end_bytes - $start_bytes);
echo $array_bytes;
```

Comment: Worth reading: [here](http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)(will not be entirely true for PHP7+) and [here](http://nikic.github.io/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I have changed the answer:

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();
$array = range(1, 100000);
echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes';
```

Regards.

**Edit 2 :**

Also try this:

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();
$array = new SplFixedArray(100000);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    $array[$i] = $i;
}
echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes';
```

http://php.net/SplFixedArray

Comment: The question asks for the (in memory) size of an array and not a way to format the return value of mempory_get_usage.

Comment: So, first define an array and then run the function. @Rangad

Comment: Thanks. The first part mimics my hunch in the original question. I'm still unsure of the value of iterating through `SplFixed` to add to memory instead of `range`. Either way, my real life use case involves an associative array. I'm open to correction.

Comment: **Php and Ram** looks like a **Plane and Road**. As you know php is interpreted language, so "Reading something from read access memory via php" is not a good idea, i think. @Ryan